# How to test Django error reporting

Tags: django

In my settings I have this...

```
ADMINS = (
    ('Me', 'me@me.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

and then in my views/urls I have these...

```
url(r'^test/$', 'main.views.test', name='page'),

def test(request):
    return render(request, '500.html', status=500)
```

I have the email settings configured and I know they work because I have emails working from that server in other parts of my site. I have everything that is said to be required in the docs, but it is still not working and IDK where to go from here. I have tried it in my live environment too with no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my email settings were correct, but there was a new setting added for error reporting titled 'SERVER_EMAIL' that was supposed to be the default from email. I had a nonexistant email address in there and that is what was causing the emails to not be sent.